# Построковый выбор

Tags: php

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть файл, который содержит построковый список информации, то есть:

```
1
2
3
```

и т.д.  мне нужно на php вывести рядом с ними checkbox'ы чтобы я мог отмечать, и удалять строку. как это можно будет сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$file = 'ya.txt';

if(isset($_POST['nums'])) {
    $array = file('ya.txt');

    if(is_array($_POST['nums'])) {
        foreach($_POST['nums'] as $ArrList) {
            unset($array[$ArrList]);
        }
    }

    file_put_contents($file, implode("", $array));
    die("Файл сохранен!");
}

$array = file($file);

echo "<form method='post'>";

foreach($array as $ArrNum => $ArrList) {
    echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='nums[]' value='$ArrNum'> $ArrList</label><br>";
}

echo "<input type='submit' value='Обновить'></form>";
```

Comment: @bazaev05 ну уж тут сами додумаете. Способ реализации я вам подкинул.

Comment: а чего [в нем][1] сложного? Уважаемый, привыкайте работать с документацией. И гугл был создан не просто так.


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 3):

Это элементарно, Ватсон:

```
<?php

$f=file("file.txt");
foreach ($f as $key=> $value) {
    print "<input type='checkbox' name='del_$key' value='$value'>";
}
?>
```

Потом реализуй перезапись файла без ненужных строк или поиск с удалением.

Comment: чую вам стоит лишний раз подучить php.  
ф-ция file - помещает всё в массив разом.
Если у вашей строки есть какое-нибудь уникальное отличее, то, для того чтобы это отличие найти, вам всё равно придётmся считывать все строки подряд.
Если вы точно знаете с какого места надо начать вывод, то надо поизвразатся с файловым указателем.
P.s. меня посетила мысля что вы наверное хотите выводить строки в которых есть смысл, минуя шапку и/или коменты.

Answer (score 1):

А может каждую строку сделать элементом массива?

Comment: через serialize попробуй